# how to run laravel existing project locally after downloading from cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cpanel

I am trying to run a laravel project after downloading from cPanel. While I run

```
composer install
composer update --no-scripts
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

none of these commands work and show **Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.** and **Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255**. Tried various solutions from other posts but couldn't run the project locally. What can I do to solve this problem and run the project locally? Screenshots are also given here. My composer.json looks like this:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5||8.1.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0||^9.0",
        "laravel/passport": "~9.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.0",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diISW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apP3r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeQX3.png)

Comment: Have you created a .env file in the root folder?

Comment: You need to install imagemagick, the error is quite clear. Don't install ignoring platform reqs, the requirements are there for a reason

Comment: Yes, I have copied the .env.example file to .env and pasted on the root folder @AnkitChauhan

Comment: ok installing imagemagick then trying the composer install again @GertB.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with the text version of all error messages. Also, keep in mind that `composer update`  **changes** packages versions, and I doubt that you really want to get into this situation?

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded the project from cPanel, the `composer install` checkes for packages from `composer.lock` which is created based on PHP version on the server. The error message itself indicates that the package is looking for a lower PHP version.

For this, you can delete the `composer.lock` file and clear the cache, and then run `composer install` again. In this case, the installation will look for packages that have the current version of PHP and then install them accordingly. As a result, there will be no dependency issue regarding the package.

Additionally, it asks you to add the "imagick" extension, you can find the link below to do so:

`https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html`

Simply edit the php.ini file and search for:

`extension=imagick.so`